# setpci not sticking on MacBook Pro 6,2

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, nvidia, macintosh, pci

I'm using the `setpci` grub command to set a device function, and the grub and pciutils versions of the command are returning different results when querying to verify it was set correctly. My questions are:

- Am I misinterpreting the output?
- If so, what is the correct way to interpret the output?
- If not, what is the actual value and how can I set it to the value I want to I can resume the instructions I'm following?

**edit:** So this question is largely academic as the audio is now working over HDMI after following the last step of the instructions, to reinstall the driver, but I'm still curious to know what's going on with the different values. The remainder of my original question follows.

There are a few questions that are similar to this, but I seem to have hit a new wall that others haven't, though I'm honestly hoping for PEBKAC! I'm running Mint 19.3, so I'm not sure if this counts as a Ubuntu question or not, so I'm posting here.

The ultimate goal is to get the nvidia-340 drivers to work so I can get sound over the mini-DP-to-HDMI cable I have. For details on what I've done so far, check out [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/posting.php?mode=reply&f=59&t=319431&sid=41dffd5eb8d863db3626ad8e35616fa9) on the Linux Mint forum.

I followed the instructions in this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/613573/234253), but querying the PCI function for the bridge from bash once logged in kept returning the original value. I found yet another [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943077/234253) that seemed to be the same problem, but it didn't help. I found `grub-efi-amd64-bin` was already installed. More importantly, I'm still not seeing the correct value querying once I've logged in after adding `insmod setpci` to my grub script. However, if I run `setpci -s "00:01.0" 3eb` from the grub command line before boot, the output I get is what I expect:

```
Register 3e of 0:01.0 is 8
```

If I run that command after boot completes and I log in, the output I get is `0a`.  I know the two `setpci` commands are actually different, but I looked at the source (see below), and they're both outputting hex. Not that `0a` could be equal to `8`.

```
$sudo setpci -v -s "00:01.0" 3e.b
0000:00:01.0 @3e = 0a
```

I'm sure the contents of `/etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf` are making it to `grub.cfg`. I even had previously added some echo statements, and they echo before boot.

```
$ tail -n +105 /boot/grub/grub.cfg | head -n 5
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf ###
insmod setpci
setpci -s "00:01.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "01:00.0" 04.b=7
### END /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf ###
$ cat -n /boot//grub/grub.cfg  | grep setpci
   106  insmod setpci
   107  setpci -s "00:01.0" 3e.b=8
   108  setpci -s "01:00.0" 04.b=7
```

Any thoughts?

It's been a long time since I've done any serious C programming and I'm way out of my depth here, but the source for the setpci grub module at [setpci.c:128](https://github.com/Jolicloud/grub2/blob/master/commands/setpci.c#L128) seems to be outputting hex. The source for the version 3.5.2 of setpci with pciutils is a little more obtuse to read, but also [setpci:160](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/v3.5.2/setpci.c#L163) seems to also be outputting hex. Of course, there's only way to interpret `0a` and one for `8`, and they're not the same anyway! Right?